# In iText, is it possible to preserve the reading-order of XFA PDF, as stored in the <traversal> and <traverse> elements, when flattening to PDF/A 1a?

Tags: pdf, itext, section508, pdfa

How can I preserve reading-order when using iText to fill and flatten an XFA PDF creating a PDF/A 1a?

The reading-order of the pre-flattened PDF is stored in the  and  elements, but this information is not being expressed in the flattened tagged PDF/A 1a document.

Specifically, my two-column form, which is read properly by JAWS prior to flattening, is incorrectly read left-to-right from top to bottom all the way across both columns instead of being reading down one column and then proceeding to the beginning of the second column.

The iText Java code looks like this:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String xml, File dest)
        throws IOException, DocumentException, InterruptedException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
    AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

    XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
    stamper.close();

    Document document = new Document();
    PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document,
            new FileOutputStream(dest), PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_1A);

    writer.setTagged();
    document.addLanguage("en-us");
    document.open();

    ICC_Profile iccProfile = ICC_Profile.getInstance(new FileInputStream(
            colorProfile));
    writer.setOutputIntents("Custom", "", "http://www.color.org",
            "sRGB IEC61966-2.1", iccProfile);
    PdfICCBased iccBased = new PdfICCBased(iccProfile);
    iccBased.remove(PdfName.ALTERNATE);
    PdfDictionary outputIntent = new PdfDictionary(PdfName.OUTPUTINTENT);
    outputIntent.put(PdfName.OUTPUTCONDITIONIDENTIFIER, new PdfString(
            "sRGB IEC61966-2.1"));
    outputIntent.put(PdfName.INFO, new PdfString("sRGB IEC61966-2.1"));
    outputIntent.put(PdfName.S, PdfName.GTS_PDFA1);
    outputIntent.put(PdfName.DESTOUTPUTPROFILE, writer.addToBody(iccBased)
            .getIndirectReference());
    writer.getExtraCatalog().put(PdfName.OUTPUTINTENTS,
            new PdfArray(outputIntent));

    PdfDictionary markInfo = new PdfDictionary(PdfName.MARKINFO);
    markInfo.put(PdfName.MARKED, new PdfBoolean(true));
    writer.getExtraCatalog().put(PdfName.MARKINFO, markInfo);

    XFAFlattener xfaf = new XFAFlattener(document, writer);
    xfaf.flatten(new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray()), false);
    document.close();

    System.out.println("The form is flattened");
}
```

Comment: Maybe i misunderstand something... But doesn't *flattening* a form imply losing its form-ness? Including any tab order?

Comment: You're correct, "tab-order" isn't the right phrasing, since there is nothing to tab through.  When processed through Adobe LiveCycle server, the same PDF and XML data produce a flattened PDF/A document with reading order, as observed through the JAWS screen reader, that's consistent with the "tab-order" set in the Adobe LiveCycle Designer UI for the fillable PDF.  LiveCycle Server translates the tab-order that the author designates in the unflattened form to some other markup/tagging/annotation in the flattened form that informs the screen-reader of the specific two-column reading order.

Comment: You might want to edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting closer, it appears that this may have been addressed here:
http://itextpdf.com/release/itext544
See the section titled "Flattening accessible files".
If anyone has been down this road, and has any tips, they would be greatly appreciated.